# Convert nullable datetime object to specifc format while using html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Mvc 4. The following is my code.

```
@Html.Bootstrap().ControlGroup().DisplayTextFor(m => m.BirthdayDate).Label().LabelText(Person.Resources.Global.BirthDay);
```

It's display the data with date and time. I want to display only date. How to do that ?

**Already I've tried with BirthDay.value.ToShortDateString() and BirthDay.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"). But this gives error, since BirthDay is Nullable DateTime**

I got the following error if i use **BirthDay.value.ToShortDateString() and BirthDay.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy") and someDate.Value.ToShortDateString()**

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Comment: `BirthDay.ToShortDateString()` or `BirthDay.ToString("d")` (assuming `BirthDay` is `DateTime`)

Comment: Already I've tried BirthDay.value.ToShortDateString() and BirthDay.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"). But this gives error, since BirthDay is Nullable DateTime

Comment: then `Birthday.Value`

Comment: Birthday.value gives error.

Comment: `Birthday.HasValue ? Birthday.Value.ToString("d") : "N/A"`

Comment: Same error I've received.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41244/discussion-between-jeeva-jsb-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I forget to mention. I am using https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/

If the object is nullable, then

For plain html helper, use like following,

**label** -

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(t => t.YourDateObject, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
```

**Textbox** -  `@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.YourDateObject, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")`

For https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/, then use like following,

```
@Html.Bootstrap().ControlGroup().DisplayTextFor(m=>m.BirthdayDate).Format("0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Label().LabelText(Person.Resources.Global.BirthDay)
```

I got reference from the following link.
[Formatted Date TextBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725057/formatted-date-textboxfor)

Answer (score 1):

Only model value can be add like these. So try to not null-able value to modal and try to use as your wish. That could be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the date is nullable you better use

```
someDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

even better:

```
someDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString();
```

of if you do not want return any date if `someDate` is `null` then you shall do the following:

```
if(someDate.HasValue)
{
    someDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: I've already mentioned nullable date time. I cant change for Nullable DateTime.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. You mentioned Nullable DateTime. All of my code works for Nullable DateTime

Comment: Conversion to specific datetime format for nullable dateTime object (for example dateTimeObj.toString("dd/mm/yyyy") or like you all specified above) is not working.

Comment: If AOCrowdFund.Resources.Global.BirthDay is of type `DateTime?` then it would. Otherwise it is not of that type.

Comment: That's only to display text not any data. m => m.BirthdayDate this is of type `DateTime?`

Comment: Then why don't you appy my suggestion on m.BirthdayDate?

Comment: How long I should repeat my same reply to you @xxMUROxx. If i use your code, I got the following error. `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.`

Comment: I try to help and understand the error. Therefore, this should also be explained. Also, the question is not written clearly.