# Html.TextBoxFors are not formatting nullable DateTimes properly

Tags: c#, razor, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've got an MVC 5 project where there's a big form, which is serialized to Knockout using:

```
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
```

Some of the form fields are textboxes using jQuery-ui-datepicker where the user can select a date:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModelDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control", @data_bind = "value: ModelDate" })
```

My problem is that if ViewModel's nullable `ModelDate` property contains a DateTime value, the textbox displays something like `2014-04-05T18:00:00`, but not `04/5/2015`.  The formatting (e.g. `"{0:d}"`) is ignored.

I don't know my string-formatting parameter is being ignored, and I'm confused about what's going on behind the scenes when the C# nullable DateTime in the ViewModel is mapped into KnockoutJS.  Is there a typical MVC or Knockout solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: Have you tried m.ModelDate.ToShortDateString() OR it might have to be "0:dd" not single d

Comment: @SythnetP I haven't tried that, and that's a very good idea, but most of my dates are Nullable<DateTime>s, which do not have the ToShortDateString() property.

Comment: Only other option I would suggest would be to check if it's not null then cast it as a DateTime or convert it to a DateTime

Comment: @SythnetP Actually, even attempting ToString() results in the error: "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.".

Comment: Well I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725057/formatted-date-textboxfor and they are using dd, are you sure your format is supported?

Comment: @SythnetP Yep, "d" represents the [C# short date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) format.

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.ModelDate, String.Format("{0:d}", Model.ModelDate)   -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961114/date-only-from-textboxfor

Comment: @SythnetP This also doesn't work.  The textbox still displays the date the same way.

Comment: Could it have something to with the data binding overriding it? Noticed @data_bind = "value: ModelDate" } could be displaying the value over what you're trying to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I solved this problem uses Razor, so it's a little dodgy, but it works.

In the background, this is a big form which is dynamically generated from a few partial views where the `@Html.TextBoxFor`s reside.  When the ViewModel is empty (a user is filling out a new form), there isn't an issue.  When the ViewModel *isn't* empty (a user is reading a submitted form) , the dates don't format correctly.  On [SythnetP's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131789/html-textboxfors-are-not-formatting-nullable-datetimes-properly?noredirect=1#comment46491137_29131789), KnockoutJS's data bindings might be overwriting the C# formatting rules.

There seem to be some solutions using Knockout, but I decided to make the model stateful with respect to whether or not it represents a "new" form versus an "old" one.

Additionally, I made the ViewModel more *viewmodel-ey* by adding some strings:

```
public string FormattedModelDate { get; set; }
```

... which are populated with "short date formatted" DateTimes when the ViewModel is created.

```
if (vm.ModelDate.HasValue)
{
    vm.FormattedModelDate = vm.ModelDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

The end result is this:

```
@{
    if (Model.IsNewForm)
    {
        // display the Html.TextBoxFor m.ModelDate with the Knockout bindings 
    }  else {
        // display the Html.TextBoxFor m.FormattedModelDate without the Knockout bindings
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

annotate your viewmodel

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
```

this will apply your formatting in your view.

Comment: I didn't mention this in the question, but that didn't work.  I think I tried virtually every iteration of `String.format` in addition to that.