# HTML: Show placeholder first in input type date

Tags: html, css

Is it possible for me to show the placeholder in input first? Right now, I can see the placeholder when I click on the input box, but I want it so that when I load the page, the placeholder can already be read instantly.

Rather than mm/dd/yyyy, it should show birth date when page is loaded[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ALK.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try input type="text" placeholder="test" ??

Answer (score 8):

```html
<input placeholder="Your Date" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date">
```

Read this Page

[How do I simulate placeholder functionality on input date field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146350/how-do-i-simulate-placeholder-functionality-on-input-date-field)

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: This is great, but the problem is when you leave the field and the dang date changes format from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD. Any idea how to have the date stay in the former format once the control is changed back to type='text' ?

Comment: You can not change it but read this link it will be helpfull for you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647290/html-5-date-field-shows-as-mm-dd-yyyy-in-chrome-even-when-valid-date-is-set

Answer (score 1):

```
        var dateofbirth="01/23/1990";
        document.getElementById('test').placeholder=dateofbirth;
```

codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OXMdvr

Answer (score 1):

You can overlap input date default placeholder with `:before` element.
It is necessary that the input element is controlled with `onChange` event

```css
/* When Input type="date" && value="" => hide Input content */

input[type="date"][value=""] {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}


/* When focus show it*/

input[type="date"]:focus {
  color: inherit;
}


/* Input type="date" && value="" => overlap with before */

input[type="date"][value=""]:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  padding-top: 4px;
  color: #aaa;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}


/* rid off before on focus */

input[type="date"]:focus:before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" placeholder="My placeholder" value="" />
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.htctu.net/html5/forms/formInputTypes.html#date
Try this link.

```
<input type=date form="sf1" name="date" placeholder="23-7-1988">
```