# Date not displaying in EditorFor

Tags: html, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display the value from the database in a editorfor field but this stays blank. The value is present in the value field but does not show in the page. 
[image]

[image]

if i use the solution from:

[Display a formatted date in an EditorFor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943797/display-a-formatted-date-in-an-editorfor)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Van, new { @Value = model.Van.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), @class="datepicker" })
```

I get the value but not the datepicker that is default provided with the EditorFor field.

Model:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Van{ get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Van, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: are you using Jquery datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a Chrome issue after changing the format to "yyyy/MM/dd" it worked.