# Change Date display format on TextAreafor directly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I was wondering if there was any way to directly change the format of a date displayed in a TextAreaFor. I know this topic has been asked alot and my problem may seem similar to those two:

[MVC DateTime Textbox Formatting Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850830/mvc-datetime-textbox-formatting-issue)

[How do you format a DateTime that's displayed by TextBoxFor() in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725057/how-do-you-format-a-datetime-thats-displayed-by-textboxfor-in-mvc3)

But I will explain why its different.
Here's the textarefor :

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m[i].DateFormation, new { @class = "textArea" })
```

Like in the questions I linked above, I could put the DisplayFormat attribute on the field but I don't have the right to modify the model or use Metadata

So My question is if there is any way to apply a format to a textareafor like you can do with a textboxfor ?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].DateFormation, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "textArea" })
```

I Tried to apply `.ToString` to my field but it seems like TextAreafor won't accept it

Note : My last case scenario is that I will Have to modify the model content with c# code in view before showing it but that just feels wrong to me and a bad practice to mix my code with the design

Comment: `TextAreaFor()` does not support formats. But why are you using a `<textarea>` to display a date? (its an element for inputting multiple lines of text and that makes no sense for a `DateTime` property - and it would never bind when you submit if you did have multiple lines of text anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Searching for Sometimes and looking into documentation ( Thanks to @StephenMuecke for the clue) `TextAreaFor` just dosen't have any option that support formating so ill just be using code before showing the date so that the time isen't shown.

I Looked into most overload and option shown for textarea on this msdn link :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions(v=vs.118).aspx

And as shown in the link the only possible overload for TextAreaFor are related to the model and none of them could accept a property to change the formating