# How to use Html.TextBoxFor with input type=date?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, input

I want to implement  in my code.  To that end, I have the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreationDate, new { @type = "date" })
```

This code generates the following HTML:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field CreationDate must be a date." 
             data-val-required="The CreationDate field is required." 
             id="CreationDate" name="CreationDate" type="date" 
             value="09/05/2012 15:02:19">
```

The value does not show up on the web page because type="date" expects data in YYYY-MM-DD format.

I've tried formatting the date, but that blows up, of course.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreationDate.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD"), 
                 new { @type = "date" })
```

How do I use TextBoxFor method to properly display the  construct?
Or should I be using some other method (I already tried EditorFor but failed)?

`CreationDate` is of type DateTime.

Comment: Specifically, I tend to use the overload mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13702321/534109

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try this;

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreationDate,
           new { @type = "date", @Value = Model.CreationDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
```

You have to handle `null` when setting the value.

OR

If you can change the `Model` you can try this;

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }
```

and in your view you can use `EditorFor` helper.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreationDate, new { @type = "date" })
```

Comment: Do not use the first option (never set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods - you lose true 2-way model binding - the correct use is `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreationDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type="date" })` and the second option just needs to be `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreationDate)` - the `type="date"` is already added by the `EditorFor()` method because of the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute

Comment: In any case, `new { @type = "date" }` does nothing at all (in [MVC5.1](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes) or higher, it would need to be `new { htmlAttributes = new { type="text" }}` and in lower versions you cannot add attributes using the `EditorFor()` method.

Comment: I was using the recommendation above "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", and it wasn't working. I went to the version in the answer, where Value is set explicitly, and it worked. Looking at the HTML generated in the first version, and I could see the Value was NOT in the form yyyy-MM-dd.

Answer (score 4):

Model design:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime CreationDate{ get; set; }
```

View Design:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.CreationDate, new { @type = "date" }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with EditorFor and the boostrap-datepicker library:

```
    <div class="input-prepend date" id="startDate" data-date=@DateTime.UtcNow data-date-format="m/d/yyyy">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate)            
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert c# Datetime to HTML-5 Date value

```
<input type="date" value="<%= SomeFieldDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")%>"/>
```