# show only the date in @Html.EditorFor helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to populate `@Html.EditorFor` helper. I have created a view model with the below property

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date only")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? YearBought { get; set; }
```

and my helper is set up as below (a)

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.YearBought)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearBought, new { @type = "date" })
```

I have also tried (b)

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.YearBought)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearBought.Value.Date)
```

Using the above format (a) nothing is displayed. Using the above format (b) `12/05/2014 00:00:00` is displayed in textbox format.

I am trying to achieve a datepicker format without a time displayed

I have reviewed several other questions but cant see what i've done different.

When I look in my database, the value is save as `2014-05-12` and when I am saving the value the EditorFor helper generates the required input facility

## questions reviewed

[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086909/how-to-use-html-textboxfor-with-input-type-date) [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961114/date-only-from-textboxfor) [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124434/display-only-date-and-no-time)....the list goes on

EDIT
just opened the console in chrome dev tools and so this message

> The specified value "12/05/14" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

I thought `DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}"` was defining how to display my date?

Comment: what is the extra `@type` for? in `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearBought, new { @type = "date" })` you can't specify htmlattributes if you use EditorFor so just curious

Comment: @type date was a last ditch attempt to make it work, no other logic than that im afraid :(

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943797/display-a-formatted-date-in-an-editorfor

Comment: Check This: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-a-formatted-date-in-a-TextBoxFor--in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use the ISO format when using `type="date"`

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date only")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? YearBought { get; set; }
```

This will display the date in the browsers culture.

Note there is no need to add `@type = "date"`. The `EditorFor()` method will add that because of the `DataType` attribute. Note also that `type="date"` is only supported in Chrome (FireFox and IE will just generate a normal textbox)

If you do want to display the format `dd/MM/yyyy` in a standard textbox then you can use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YearBought, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

Comment: When I use same syntax in Editor for then it does not work  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.YearBought, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")

Comment: @AshishShukla, Because `EditorFor()` does not support that syntax. All you need is `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YearBought)` - the `EditorFor() method respects values in the `DataType` and `DisplayFormat` attributes

Comment: To use `@Html.EditorFor()` you have to specify the format as `yyyy-MM-dd`, not like how it's shown in that `TextBoxFor`, above. Like it did Ashish, it might confuse some people into thinking you can use that format for `EditorFor` - you're right, you can't.  But just doing `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.YearBought)` is definitely not enough, even with the model attributes.  See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247295/show-only-the-date-in-html-editorfor-helper/52861439#52861439

Answer (score 3):

As it says in Stephen's answer, you have to make your formats match between the tags in your model to what is shown in the View, and it should be of the `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO) format, regardless of how you actually want to display the date:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

// .... your namespace .... your class....

[DisplayName("Year Bought")]
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Date only")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? YearBought { get; set; }
```

And he's right, because we have `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`, we don't need `@type = date` in our `HtmlAttributes` on the View.

Where my answer differs from his is how to actually apply the value from the Model to the control on the View.  Since `YearBought` is a `Nullable<DateTime>`, we have to set it with its value a certain way, using `.Value`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearBought, 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", 
    @Value = Model.YearBought.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") } })
```

Paying close attention to set the `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.  It's not going to display in the box like that, though - at least for me - probably because my U.S. Regional settings on my computer take over and display it as `MM/dd/yyyy` regardless.  This might confuse some, but it's better to just "do" and not worry about it.

If `YearBought` was just a straight `DateTime` instead of a `DateTime?`, it would be without the `.Value`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearBought, 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", 
    @Value = Model.YearBought != null ? 
    Model.YearBought.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null } })
```

Comment: You NEVER set the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods (unless you are trying to screw up model binding).

Comment: @StephenMuecke My model binding was already screwed up, because it wasn't working without this.  Doing what I did above was the only thing I was able to do to get it to work.  I posted this because I imagine it could happen to someone else, as well.

Comment: The you have something else causing it. All the `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls correctly set the `value` attribute by first reading it from `ModelState`, then the `ViewDataDictionary` and finally from the actual model value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Don't think so.  I have a ViewModel I was using that looks just like above. `myViewModel.startdt = DateTime.Now;` Passed it to my view with a `return View("MyView", myViewModel);` and had `using @model TestSite.ViewModels.MyViewModel` at the top.  All my `EditorFor()` boxes were fine and posting from my model after a form postback, but the `EditorFor()` ones I was filling with dates were just "mm/dd/yyyy" if not setting a `@Value`.  I'm not the only answer to ever say to use that, by the way:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943797/display-a-formatted-date-in-an-editorfor

Comment: Another wrong answer from a mvc beginner who does not know what they are doing or how the `HtmlHelper` methods work (without seeing your code, all I can do is guess that you are trying to change the value in your controller  after a value has been added to `ModelState`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke What I'm doing has to be fairly common & I don't think I'm a novice-tho maybe not as adv as you. As I said, it was a postback onto a form. I set an empty model w/some prefilled properties (not the Start Date, but Created By, Created Date, etc.) in my Controller `Index()`, which does a `return View(myViewModel);`. Click a Save button after I upload a file-launches `Upload()` that reads properties & sets `myViewModel.startdt = DateTime.Now;` then it does `return View("Index", myViewModel);` to update the original model with my new values. As I said, only the dates have issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182047/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-vapcguy).

Answer (score 0):

I would make your view model's `YearBought` property a `String` for the easiest manipulation.  The server can format the date, it can do the parsing on postback, and you can still use the `DataType.Date` data annotation for jQuery validation.  This also ensures that the display value will be exactly what you want prior to being submitted to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the HTML type attribute, you can use an `EditorTemplate` in MVC to put the markup, CSS, and JS needed to render a custom editor for a known C# datatype like `DateTime`.

Here is [a walkthrough](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx) for creating a custom 'EditorTemplate' in MVC (although not for a Date data type, but concept is the same)