# Datetime showing when I just want date mvc textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, adminlte

I am using the date picker in admin lte but no mater what I do the date time picker will show.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateReported)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateReported, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control 
datetimepicker" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateReported)
```

You will see the generated html is as follows.

```
<input class="form-control datetimepicker text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val- 
required="The DateReported field is required." id="DateReported" name="DateReported" type="datetime- 
local" value="0001-01-01T00:00:00.000" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="DateReported-error" 
aria-invalid="false">
```

But even though I have in my scripts done this.

And I have tried this.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateReported)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateReported, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control 
dateicker" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateReported)

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
      $('.DateRaised').datepicker();
      $('.DateReported').datepicker();

     });
```

Even if I set it as such Presume its because it gets datetime data type from my model how do I show only date part in textbox.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateReported)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateReported, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control 
datepicker" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateReported)
```

But this still procduces this view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247295/show-only-the-date-in-html-editorfor-helper

Comment: similar: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1011311/MVC-DateTime-EditorFor-displaying-date-and-also-TI

Comment: @Nikki9696 your first answer worked thanks very much how does one show a blank field however and not just 01/01/01

Comment: probably have to make your property nullable

Answer (score 0):

have you tried fixing it from the Model ?

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DateReported{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mention the date format on initializing datepicker in Jquery function:

```
$(function () {
     $('.DateRaised').datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    });
});
```