# C# MVC in Edge (after it replaced Internet Explorer) Date error

Tags: c#

I started to get a View error **Field NextContactDate is not a Date** when we changed from Internet explorer to Edge. I wanted to resolve this and stop it from happening. This was in a C# application originally written in 2012 and running on PCs where they had replaced WIN 7 PCS with WIN 10.
The original View Code for the field in Edit.cshtml was:

```
<tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.sitestatus.StatusDate)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.sitestatus.StatusDate, new { @Value = Model.sitestatus.StatusDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), id = "dp", style = "width:90px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sitestatus.StatusDate)</td>
        <td>The Date of the Status Change</td>
</tr>
```

How do we get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by amending the Site Status Edit.cshtml code:

```
<tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.sitestatus.StatusDate)</td>
        <td>@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.sitestatus.StatusDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { id="dp", style="width:90px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sitestatus.StatusDate)
        @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }</td>
</tr>
```

The trick was to include Html.EnableClientValidation false around the code but this is a new one on me. Anyone know what it does and what else it may affect ie does it allow Chrome to work on dates the same as IE and Edge?

Comment: Disabling validation is not a fix, it's a very serious bug. The original code was buggy - instead of binding to a date property and letting the client format it, it converted the DateTime value into a localized string.

Comment: All modern browsers have [date and datetime input types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date). Perhaps a better solution would be to use `input type="date"`. [This probably duplicate question shows how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086909/how-to-use-html-textboxfor-with-input-type-date)

Comment: I am all for a better solution

Comment: Thanks so much for your rapid reply. I am all for a better solution but this was the best I could come up with after spending ages trawling the internet. If you are able to provide a better one I will try it and report back.

Comment: Check the duplicate in that case. There were a lot of changes since 2012 though, both in HTML and Javascript, and the 8-year old validation scripts may fail in other places. The error you posted came from Javascript, because the string value couldn't be parsed as a Date. You may have to upgrade the client-side validation libraries

Comment: A *lot* of validation problems go away simply by using the "new" input types.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis this is the first time I have had such a confident reply - I have not tried the potential solution yet as it looks like it may require a db change which may take a while to implement. The fix that looked like it had worked was only a change to the View and nothing else which is what made it attractive.