# input value attribute renders twice

Tags: html, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

This is a rather interesting issue that was quite hard to spot...and I cannot resolve it. In a nutshell, I have the following in a view trying to render a date field (ignore archiac syntax - it's an old project);

```
        <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfRenewal, 
                new { 
                    type = "date",
                    placeholder = "DD/MM/YYYY",
                    Value = (Model.DateOfRenewal != null) ? Model.DateOfRenewal.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : "" 
                })%>
```

Now on the model, the date format attribute is set to "dd/MM/yyyy" appropriately. We're rendering to "yyyy-MM-dd" when generating the HTML in order for a jquery library (webshim polyfiller) to pick up the date correctly when it starts running against the field. I don't have control over this library so I'm stuck with it and I have control only over the MVC side of things.

What's happening is that the field above looks ok when you inspect it but viewing the source shows the following;

```
<input Value="2008-05-12" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Renewal Date must be a date." 
       id="Ratings_DateOfRenewal" 
       name="Ratings.DateOfRenewal" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" 
       type="date" 
       value="12/05/2008 00:00:00" />
```

Notice that `Value` and `value` are both present. The lower case version is what goes in there as part of `TextBoxFor` and the uppercase `Value` is what appears in my custom attribute when specifying in the view.

However, changing the custom attribute in the view from an uppercase to a lower case is runs fine but it does *not* have the custom date format. As a result, I get a blank field as webshim cannot interpret it.

Is there anyway to get a custom date format without;

- Changing the model attribute (required for server side validation)
- Changing/modifying the jquery library

In a nutshell, is there a way to get the custom formatted date as a single, lowercase `value` html attribute when rendered?

**EDIT**
The marked answer below changes the lowercase `value` to the specified format. To fulfill the original request, the MVC markup has to change to a lowercase `value` as well. This fixes the issue.

**EDIT2**
The duplicate mark is invalid. While the situation is very close, none of the answers in the linked post work in this situation - inherently marking it as different.

Comment: you shouldn't need to specify the value.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on getting the date format to "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: @DanielA.White, not a duplicate. I've already checked quite a few posts on SO before posting and had already come across that one

Comment: from the link daniel posted there is an answer for MVC4 and up which seems to be a reasonable solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13702321/372529

Comment: @DanielA.White: close, but not quite the same situation, and none of the answers address the OP's problem

Comment: @phillip that worked, actually (somewhat to my surprise, I thought that would affect accepted input values on the POST), thank you! I'll mark as accepted answer if posted below