# ASP.Net Html.TextBoxFor format for datetime param not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code in cshtml:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDateTime, new { @class = "lbl100" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDateTime, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control control120" })
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDateTime, new { @class = "lbl100" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDateTime, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control control120" })
```

there are two ways to get this action, from menu with Ajax.Actionlink
and form pagedlist actionlink

this is the value form menu:
[image]

this is the value form pagedlist:
[image]

why the format param not work?

Answer (score 0):

If plain `String.Format` inside `TextBoxFor` doesn't work, place formatting style using `DisplayFormat` on your `DateTime` model properties to enforce date input.

```
[DisplayName("Start Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)] // if HTML5 is used you can apply this attribute
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }

[DisplayName("End Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)] // if HTML5 is used you can apply this attribute
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
```

Useful reference: [Date only from TextBoxFor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961114/date-only-from-textboxfor)