# ArgumentException on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

This is the exception I get:

*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'birthDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddMember(System.String, System.String, System.DateTime, Int32, System.String)' in 'AuthSys.Controllers.MemberController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameternavn: parameters*

My view looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">                
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { size = "50", @type = "date", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { maxlength = "3", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SportType)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SportType, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Opret" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
```

My contoller:

```
public ActionResult AddMember(string fName, string lName, DateTime birthDate, int age, string sportType)
{
    var member = new Member() { FirstName = fName, LastName = lName, Age = age, SportType = sportType, BirthDate = birthDate};
    coloContext.Members.Add(member);
    coloContext.SaveChanges();         
    return View(member);
}
```

And the viewmodel

```
public class MemberViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }       
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }                       
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }        
    public int Age { get; set; }        
    public string SportType { get; set; }
}
```

The error comes when I try to run my application. Searching on this error over the internet, they all point to the routing, which confuses me even more. I do not fully understand the error message. It looks like it says that Date is a null value, but in the view, the user will be providing the date parameter. Can anyone please explain what my problem is? Thanks a lot.

In case needed, my routing looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Member", action = "AddMember", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

---------------------Update------------------------

Sorry, I did not think the full code of the view was necassary. Here is the full code

```
    @model AuthSys.ViewModels.MemberViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Medlem";
}

<h2>Member</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="imageComponent">
            <div class="memberPhoto">
                <p>Billed mangler</p>
                <br />
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Tag et billed" style="float:right; margin-right: 20px;" />
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">                
                <br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { size = "50", @type = "date", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { maxlength = "3", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SportType)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SportType, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Opret" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Registrerede medlemmer", "RegisteredMembers")    
</div>
```

Comment: from where you calling addmember function show that code or html

Comment: That would be from the view. The first code that I provided on top

Comment: Is this a form that's submitting to `AddMember`?

Comment: Can you please wrap your code inside the `form` HTML attribute. You can use @Html.BeginForm API

Comment: share full html with form tag

Comment: There are a couple of good answers in this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961114/date-only-from-textboxfor). I feel that the issue is in the view code and a null value is passed into the controller action. You can check that by making the param in the action as nullable and checking the value if it's coming in as null.

Comment: I added the full code for the view now

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code is not wrapped inside the form. So while submitting a request, the form binding is not happening for parameters.

**Solution** - Wrap the code inside Form. See the below code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMember", "<<ControllerName>>", new { }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">                
                <br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { size = "50", @type = "date", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { maxlength = "3", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SportType)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SportType, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50", @class = "AddMemberControls" })
                <br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Opret" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div> 
}
```